# Google Contact API

Tags: oauth

I am trying to retrieve all my contacts using Google Contact API. For this I used Oauth authentication and Google Contact API.

I got "Access Token" from Google OAuth 2.0. But here my question is how can I retrieve my contacts using this "Access Token". How to use this access token in my code. Can any one help me on this please. If possible any sample code snippet please.

I stuck over here. Please help me on this...

Thanks & Regards,
Amar Thondapu

Answer (score 1):

This sample should help: https://github.com/jcleblanc/oauth/blob/master/oauth2-php-google/complete.php.  Specifically, look at line 21:

```
$contact_url = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?oauth_token=" . $token->access_token;
```

That URI (with the access token) should be where you can make an HTTP GET request to in order to obtain the contacts.  Hopefully they haven't changed the URI in the 2 years since that sample was created.

Jon

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jonathan. But I am a Java developer I don't the php programming. If you have any Java related stuff can you please point me. Once again Thanks for your reply.:)

Comment: Hi Amar, sorry I was just pointing out with the sample that you should be able to use https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?oauth_token=TOKEN as the URI that you make a request to to get the contacts for a user, using the access token.  Just replace TOKEN with your access token and you should be all set.